# Mock 3rd Party API calls in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, jackson, mockito

So the current situation is such. I have build an app and also running some tests on the controller. However the tests hit the actual 3rd party API and then jackson does binding on result to map in to POJO objects.

I am kind of unsure how to mock the whole thing without me ending up population the POJO manually . I am looking for something which would take the mock json response and bind it to the POJO and I can verify it matches data on the mock json.

Here is sample of my third part calling API

```
/**
 * Makes the API call and stores result in POJO
 * It should also gracefully handle any errors
 * @return
 */
public 3rdPartySearchResult searchAPICall(){
    if(productQuery==null||productQuery.isEmpty() || productQuery.trim().isEmpty()){
        throw new NullPointerException("Query string cannot be empty");
    }
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    WalmartSearchResult wsr = restTemplate.getForObject(3rdPartyAPIDetails.searchUrl, 3rdPartyPOJO.class,3rdPartyAPIDetails.APIKey,productQuery);
    return wsr;
}
```

iI somehow need to mock restTemplate.getForObject to point to mock json file.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279380/how-to-mock-response-of-rest-call-in-spring-when-you-cant-controll-when-the-res

Answer (score 0):

The following example test shows one way to do it, using the JMockit mocking library:

```
@Test
public void exampleTestForSearchAPICall(@Mocked RestTemplate rest) {
    SearchAPI searchAPI = new SearchAPI(...productQuery...);

    3rdPartySearchResult result = searchAPI.searchAPICall();

    assertNotNull(result);

    // Verify the expected call to RestTemplate:
    new Verifications() {{ rest.getForObject(...argument values and/or matchers...); }};
}
```